# jq: iterate over every element of list and replace it with value

Tags: bash, jq

I've got this json-file:

```json
{
  "name": "market",
  "type": "grocery",
  "shelves": {
    "upper_one": [
      "23423565",
      "23552352",
      "08789089"
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to iterate over every element of an list (upper_one), and replace it with other value.

---

I've tried this code:

```
#/bin/bash

for product in $(cat first-shop.json| jq -r '.shelves.upper_one[]')
do
  cat first-shop.json| jq --arg id "$((1 + $RANDOM % 10))" --arg product "$product" -r '.shelves.upper_one[]|select(. == $product)|= $id' 
done
```

But I got this kind of output:

```
1
23552352
08789089
23423565
10
08789089
23423565
23552352
7
```

Is it possible to iterate over list with jq, replace values with value from another function (like $id in the code), and print the whole final json with substituted values?

---

I need this kind of output:

```json
{
  "name": "market",
  "type": "grocery",
  "shelves": {
    "upper_one": [
      "1",
      "10",
      "7"
    ]
  }
}
```

not just elements of "upper_one" list thrice.

Comment: What do you want to replace them with? Random numbers?

Comment: No, I have another function in the script, that would generate the text I need. It's just  an example.

Comment: Could you show a sample output of your script ? Does it already have the json quotes for example ?

Comment: @Aserre sample output is in "But I got this kind of output:" section

Comment: I meant when you say `I have another function in the script, that would generate the text I need`. Does simply generate the text, or is it proper json (with quotes) ?

Comment: @Aserre Ahh - it's generating text, not json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for product in $(jq -r '.shelves.upper_one[]' input.json)
do
    id="$((1 + $RANDOM % 10))"
    newIds+=("$id")
done

jq  '.shelves.upper_one = $ARGS.positional' input.json --args "${newIds[@]}"
```

Comment: Great one! But the first element will be an empty string as there's space in front of "$id" in  ```newIds=("${newIds[@]}" "$id")```, replace it with ```newIds+=("$id")``` could solve this.

Comment: @star indeed ! nice catch

Answer (score -1):

IMHO its better to use some scripting language and manipulate objects programmatically. If bash and jq is your only option - this do the job though not nice

```
$ jq '.shelves.upper_one[] |= (sub("23423565";"1") | sub("23552352";"10") | sub("08789089";"7"))' your.json
{
  "name": "market",
  "type": "grocery",
  "shelves": {
    "upper_one": [
      "1",
      "10",
      "7"
    ]
  }
}
```

consider conversion to numbers with `| tonumber`

Comment: But I need it to be changed not with the static numbers, but numbers i got from another function - thats the main trouble.